# F1 student in US, correcting mistake in wrong tax form filed

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, f1-student-visa, form-1040x

I noticed a similar question [In the US as an F-1 student, filed the wrong form last year](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46188/in-the-us-as-an-f-1-student-filed-the-wrong-form-last-year). But I have something additional to ask.

I am a F1 student nonresident alien and, in 2014, I filed form 1040EZ instead of 1040NR-EZ. I received a refund as well. Now I want to correct this mistake. In the referenced question I found that I have to complete 1040X. Do I just complete form 1040X completing biographical page? Or do I have to file form 1040NR-EZ as well? Also, I am confused how the process works since I already received refund. Any comments?

Comment: If you're in doubt, you can call the IRS service center and ask. If you do this, record the "operator number" that the person gives you at the beginning of the call and document the contents of the call for your own records. I personally would call for a situation like this if I had any doubt at all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to file form 1040X, and you need to attach all the forms that changed to it. In your case, you'll need to redo your tax return entirely since the base form you used (1040) is incorrect and you should have used 1040NR.

So yes, you need to attach the correct form 1040NR-EZ and whatever schedules (Schedule OI comes to mind, and may be other forms - read the instructions to form 1040NR-EZ). It is likely that you'll end up owing more taxes than in the original return since you wouldn't be able to claim the standard deduction. You'll have to repay back whatever you owe on top of the amount in the 1040EZ you originally filed, and calculate the interest on the difference (again - read the [instructions to form 1040X](https://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-1040X)). When you file - you attach a check on the difference + interest to your filing. You can leave the interest calculation to the IRS - just attach a check for the actual difference and let them send you a letter about the interest you owe, then send them another check on whatever amount they calculated.