# I overlooked to file Form 8889 (HSA contribution) on my tax return. Should I file an amended return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, hsa, form-1040x, amended-tax-return

I filed a 1040NR-EZ tax return. Only after I mailed it, I realized that I had an HSA which requires Form 8889 and the non-simplified 1040NR to be filed. My W-2 does show a W contribution in Box 12.

If I file an amended return, the refund won't change since my own HSA contribution was $0.01 (how funny is that?) and my employer's HSA contribution is just a two-figure number.

Is it necessary to file an amended return? If the amounts were larger, I would do this straight-away, but for just a $0.01 change in the AGI I'm not sure if this is worth the effort (on my as well as on IRS's side)? The IRS should've received my 1040NR-EZ about four weeks ago but I haven't heard anything from them yet.

Comment: Did you receive a 1099-SA from your bank/HSA custodian?

Comment: No, but I received a 5498-SA Tax Form (the Copy B For Participant).

Comment: Did you efile or on paper? I'm guessing the latter. If so, 4 weeks is about the minimum and up to 8 weeks is normal; see also (my) https://money.stackexchange.com/a/94161/24436 . Even then IRS won't send notices for very small amounts because it costs them money -- not just to actually send the notices, which is mostly computerized, but for staff time to handle the responses. If they don't bother, I don't think you're required to either.

Comment: Yes, I've filed on paper. Thanks for the info!
I guess I'll see if/when/what they respond. For my state return, I'll attach the corrected federal return (I've already prepared it; wasn't actually that hard in the end).

Comment: Any updates? Did you end up sending a corrected return? Did you hear from the IRS?

Comment: I prepared the correct 1040NR and attached that one to my state tax return, but I never mailed the corrected one to the IRS and they refunded according to the 1040NR-EZ.

Answer (score -1):

You might have done your taxes correctly by mistake.

So HSA contributions are only tax deductible if you contribute money from your own bank.

https://hsastore.com/learn/taxes/hsa-tax-deduction

I have a feeling you fall under the payroll pre-tax hsa contributions. Where your company pays for you using money from your paycheck.

In this case, tax was never taken away from you, ergo you wont/shouldn't need them back.

Comment: OP already knows that it won’t make a difference to the bottom line of his tax return. However, because money did go in to his HSA, he is normally required to file. He did not do his taxes correctly by mistake. The question is, should he file an amended return to fix this even though the bottom line will not change? You haven’t really answered this, and your answer implies that it was correct to skip the 8889 in the first place, which is wrong.